# Symfony Security rout admin

Tags: php, security, symfony

I want protected url /admin/ and I use symfony book but not work fine, I have user not user bundle just entity user and field roles = ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_USER, ROLE_FREELANCER. I have SecurityBundle in standard complete. Now if I enter with Developer who have ROLE_FREELNANCER I go to tha action for this role but if I past url admin/tim/dashboard this Developer enter for this url, this wrong. Help please.
this my security:

```
security:
encoders:
    Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1
    Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_CLIENT:   ROLE_USER
    ROLE_COMPANY:  ROLE_USER
    ROLE_FREELANCER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:    ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [user_db, user_dev, in_memory]
            providers: [user_dev, in_memory]
    user_db:
        entity: { class: Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users, property: email }
    user_dev:
        entity: { class: Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer, property: email }
    in_memory:
       memory:
         users:
            admin_tyty: { password: adminpass_tyty, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }


firewalls:
    default:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout:
              path:   /logout
              invalidate_session: false

 access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /admin/(.*), roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

and my action

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
  public function loginAction(Request $request)
  {

    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('ArtelProfileBundle:Security:login.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'home_page' => $this->container->getParameter('home_page'),
            'phone_in_header' => $this->container->getParameter('phone_in_header'),
            'error'         => $error,
            'db_url' => $this->container->getParameter('db_url'),
            'api_url' => $this->container->getParameter('api_url'),
            'mauth_url' => $this->container->getParameter('mauth_url'),
            'gaID' => $this->container->getParameter('gaID'),
            'ymID' => $this->container->getParameter('ymID')
        )
    );
}

public function securityCheckAction()
{
    // Роут
}

public function indexAction()
{

    $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');

    if ( $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') == false ) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login_route'));
    }

    $role = $this->getUser()->getRoles();
    if($role[0] == 'ROLE_FREELANCER')
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('artel_profile_homepage', array('username' => $this->getUser()->getUsername())));
    }
    elseif($role[0] == 'ROLE_COMPANY')
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('artel_user_profile_homepage', array('username' => $this->getUser()->getUsername())));
    }

    if($role[0] == 'ROLE_ADMIN')
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_tim_dashboard'));
    }
    else

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: Move `- { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }` one line up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your access_control setting allow to do this. Change order of rules:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```